Sending Inertia response to post request with single id without full component re-render
I am trying to create a stepper flow in React using Inertia and Laravel. I have created an Inertia post request, but when I hit that in the backend, the document I am trying to create gets created. However, I need the document ID so that I can use that ID to update that same document in steps 2 and 3.
Here is my request code
const onFormSave = (step) => {
    if (stepOneParentCategory == '1'){
      try {
        Inertia.post('/save-document', { doc_policy_content:stepTwoPolicyEditorContent, doc_framework_content:valueFrameworkEditor,cat_name: stepOneNewCategory , doc_user_id: "1" , parent_cat_type:'policy' , step_no:step  }, {
          onSuccess: (response) => {
            // Check the response data here
            console.log('Response data:', response.props.data);
          },
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving document:', error);
      }
    } else if (stepOneParentCategory == '2') {
      Inertia.post('/save-document', { doc_policy_content:stepTwoPolicyEditorContent, doc_framework_content:valueFrameworkEditor , doc_user_id: "1" , project_id:stepOneProjectId , parent_cat_type:'project', step_no:step  });
    }
  }

Here is my response code
$document_data = $request->all();

if($document_data['step_no'] === 0){
    if($document_data['parent_cat_type'] == 'policy'){
        $cat_id =  $this->createPolicyCategory($document_data['cat_name']);

        if ($cat_id !== 500) {
          $document_id = $this->createDocumentAndCategory($document_data, $cat_id,'draft','policy');
          $categories = Categories::where('cat_parent_cat_id', null)->get();
          $projects = Projects::all();

        }else {
          return back()->with(['error' => 'Category already exists']);
        }       
    }else {
        $this->createDocumentAndCategory($document_data,'','draft','project');
    }
}elseif ($document_data['step_no'] === 1) {
    # code...
}elseif ($document_data['step_no'] === 2) {
    # code...
}

I have tried Inertia::render, but that way, my other required props in the component become null, and my screen goes blank. I have tried to share data, but I cannot access the document ID on the client side.

after creating the document in the first step, store the document ID in the session: $request->session()->put('document_id', $document_id); Then to retrieve it $document_id = $request->session()->get('document_id');

I will try this way i guess thanks
